# jQuery UI Draggable: Doesnt revert to original location

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I have enabled dragging and dropping table rows on my web page (code below). Unfortunately when I use `{ revert: invalid }` the row returns to its original location but with a slight offset. It looks to be about 5px down and to the right.  This seems odd as I clone the entire table row. Can anyone offer any reason as to why?

```
function setupDragDrop(source, target) {
    source.draggable({
        revert: 'invalid',
        opacity: 0.9,
        cursor: 'move',
        helper: function(event) {
            var target = $(event.target).closest('tr');
            var target_children = target.children();

            var clone = target.clone();

            clone.children().width(function(i,val) {
                return target_children.eq(i).width();
            });

            return $('<div class="configbox drag-row"><table class="lanes"></table></div>')
                .find('table').append(clone).end();
        },
        start : function() {
            //this.style.display="none";
        },
        stop: function() {
            //this.style.display="";
        },
        appendTo: 'body'
    });

    target.droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).parent().append(ui.draggable);
        },
        accept: source.selector
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a work around I have changed the revert function to alter the original start position to account for the weird offset like so:

```
revert: function (event, ui) {
    //overwrite original position
    $(this).data("draggable").originalPosition = {
        top: $(this).data("draggable").originalPosition.top - 9,
        left: $(this).data("draggable").originalPosition.left - 9
    };
    return !event;
},
```